# Problem with function reading all attributes of given node

Tags: javascript, html, dom, attributes

```
// function to read all attributes

function get_attributes(source_node) {       // source of attributes
  var i, attribute, size, tab = [];

  attribute = { name: "", value: "" }     // new type
  size = source_node.attributes.length;       // reading size

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    attribute.name = source_node.attributes[i].name;
    attribute.value = source_node.attributes[i].value;
    tab[i] = attribute;                                 //putting attribute into table
    alert(tab[i].name + " - " + tab[i].value);
  }


  return tab;   //returning filled table
}
```

Problem is, table (tab) consists only last red parameter :(
Anyone?

Comment: Can you post a log of your `source_node` parameter?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Source_node can be anything. ie "document.body"

it works if declared inside loop
...
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {

VAR attribute =[];

```
attribute.name = source_node.attributes[i].name;
attribute.value = source_node.attributes[i].value;
```

tab[i] = attribute;                                 //putting attribute into table

}

....